# Messenger bot PHP variables

Tags: php, mysql, curl, session-variables, facebook-messenger

need to ask:

1.) 
How to fetch variable from Messenger bot message.

For example: user send to bot question "What is the time in Japan"

How to fetch the city the user asks? How to fetch **Japan**?

2.)

I save every message to my database with array of sender recipient etc. ...

How to make step by step questions?

For example:

**user sends:** buy 2 dvd

**bot answer:** please send your full name

**user answer:** John Doe

**bot answer:** please send your adress

**user answer:** 1st, Great Street, Tokio

**bot answer:** thank you, everythig saved.

I think this cannot be done with only IF statement but with something like session, or memory, or something. The bot must to know, that user want to buy something and if yes, he must ask about name and also user adress.

I was create simple BOT with some strings, but I cannot know, how to do this. And FB documentation about bot not help me.

Thanks for help, have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the current question number and increment it ,and instead make if statment try to use switch/case for current question number

```
switch ($c) {

   case 4 :

                //update the current question number in db and show the next question


                $bot->send(new StructuredMessage($message['sender']['id'],
                    StructuredMessage::TYPE_BUTTON,
                    [
                        'text' => 'Enter your Facebook profile link',
                        'buttons' => [
                            new MessageButton(MessageButton::TYPE_POSTBACK,                                  'Skip')

                        ]
                    ]
                ));
                break;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a database to store user states, you can't store it in variables as variables die per post back. Just create a database column in a table of you choice called status and then send user a message text based on current status.